# Error "e=2: system cannot find file" encountered using Makefile, how can i solve it?

Tags: windows, makefile

so, i've recently installed Makefile and while trying to use it it gives me this error:

`cp build/main.bin build/main_floppy.img process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cp build/main.bin build/main_floppy.img, ...) failed. make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified. make: *** [Makefile:7: build/main_floppy.img] Error 2`

i am a newbie to Makefile (installed with Chocolatey) but here is the code i used to make the file, this code should use NASM to make a binary file and then use that binary file to make an .img file:

```
ASM=nasm

SRC_DIR=src
BUILD_DIR=build

$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img: $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin
    cp $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img
    truncate -s 1440k $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img

$(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin: $(SRC_DIR)/main.asm
    $(ASM) $(SRC_DIR)/main.asm -f bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin
```

since, like i said, i am a noob, i tried searching for a solution, but it didn't work, also the code is from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t-SPC7Tczc&list=PLFjM7v6KGMpiH2G-kT781ByCNC_0pKpPN) so i tried searching in the comments but i couldn't find a solution.
In the end i tried to make a text file and i renamed it as main_floppy.img because i was desperate and it seemed like it could work.

Comment: This makefile is written for a POSIX system such as Linux or MacOS.  You are working on a Windows system, so it won't work.  In this specific case, `cp` is a POSIX command to copy files and that command doesn't exist on Windows.  But even if you did get that (say, by installing Git for Windows which has some ports of various POSIX tools) this makefile needs more advanced commands like `truncate` which you won't find there.

Comment: @MadScientist thank you for the answer, i didn't notice that. Now i updated the file using the "copy" command and it works